Problems using nav2 on a real robot
I' m trying to use nav2 on a real robot. However, I have several problems such as: After I had launched launch_robot.launch.py and rplidar.launch.py on my Pi 4 through ssh, I launched rviz2, online_async_launch.py, joystick.launch.py, and navigation_launch.py in my dev laptop I got several in all terminals even though gazebo working all fine with nav2.
lifecycle_manager-8] [INFO] [1714872601.825479528] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Activating controller_server
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872601.825791446] [controller_server]: Activating
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872601.825842549] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Activating
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872601.825864743] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Checking transform
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872601.825923228] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872602.326008008] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872602.826005261] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872603.326004334] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872603.825969343] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872604.325970218] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872604.826097754] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872605.326291369] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872605.826255494] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872606.325990371] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872606.825955800] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872648.825995205] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872649.326018277] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872649.825989768] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872650.326331421] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872650.825992587] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872651.325960263] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872651.825970998] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872652.325985661] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872652.826025557] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872653.325957098] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872653.825983061] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872654.325955605] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872654.825967256] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872655.325962003] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872655.826001006] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872656.326037715] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872656.825952167] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872657.326024555] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872657.825951681] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872658.325982339] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872658.825954447] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872659.325956333] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872659.825954854] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872660.326069893] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872660.825999163] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872661.326003025] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872661.825989869] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-1] [ERROR] [1714872661.826050938] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Failed to activate local_costmap because transform from base_link to odom did not become available before timeout
[lifecycle_manager-8] [ERROR] [1714872661.826607425] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Failed to change state for node: controller_server
[lifecycle_manager-8] [ERROR] [1714872661.826650711] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Failed to bring up all requested nodes. Aborting bringup.
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[velocity_smoother-7] [INFO] [1714872673.994069582] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[velocity_smoother-7] [INFO] [1714872673.994184700] [velocity_smoother]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (velocity_smoother)
[velocity_smoother-7] [INFO] [1714872673.994258172] [velocity_smoother]: Cleaning up
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1714872673.994069672] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1714872673.994069647] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1714872673.994184585] [bt_navigator]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (bt_navigator)
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1714872673.994258273] [bt_navigator]: Cleaning up
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1714872673.994069487] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1714872673.994184284] [planner_server]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (planner_server)
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1714872673.994258949] [planner_server]: Cleaning up
[lifecycle_manager-8] [INFO] [1714872673.994081251] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[lifecycle_manager-8] [INFO] [1714872673.994184282] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Running Nav2 LifecycleManager rcl preshutdown (lifecycle_manager_navigation)
[waypoint_follower-6] [INFO] [1714872673.994081140] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[waypoint_follower-6] [INFO] [1714872673.994212433] [waypoint_follower]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (waypoint_follower)
[waypoint_follower-6] [INFO] [1714872673.994273896] [waypoint_follower]: Cleaning up
[smoother_server-2] [INFO] [1714872673.994124873] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[smoother_server-2] [INFO] [1714872673.994191590] [smoother_server]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (smoother_server)
[smoother_server-2] [INFO] [1714872673.994258205] [smoother_server]: Cleaning up
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872673.994134704] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872673.994219448] [controller_server]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (controller_server)
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872673.994280403] [controller_server]: Cleaning up
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714872673.994469098] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Cleaning up
[velocity_smoother-7] [INFO] [1714872673.994292861] [velocity_smoother]: Destroying bond (velocity_smoother) to lifecycle manager.
[velocity_smoother-7] [INFO] [1714872673.995858091] [velocity_smoother]: Destroying
[velocity_smoother-7] [ERROR] [1714872673.995888767] [velocity_smoother]: Unable to start transition 5 from current state shuttingdown: Could not publish transition: publisher's context is invalid, at ./src/rcl/publisher.c:423, at ./src/rcl_lifecycle.c:368
[velocity_smoother-7] [WARN] [1714872673.995902307] [rclcpp_lifecycle]: Shutdown error in destruction of LifecycleNode: final state(unconfigured)
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1714872673.994779810] [behavior_server]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (behavior_server)
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1714872673.994842256] [behavior_server]: Cleaning up
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1714872674.005412304] [behavior_server]: Destroying bond (behavior_server) to lifecycle manager.
[waypoint_follower-6] [INFO] [1714872674.005884125] [waypoint_follower]: Destroying bond (waypoint_follower) to lifecycle manager.
[smoother_server-2] [INFO] [1714872674.012960301] [smoother_server]: Destroying bond (smoother_server) to lifecycle manager.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1714872674.014435026] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Cleaning up
[waypoint_follower-6] [INFO] [1714872674.017212323] [waypoint_follower]: Destroying
[waypoint_follower-6] [ERROR] [1714872674.017250067] [waypoint_follower]: Unable to start transition 5 from current state shuttingdown: Could not publish transition: publisher's context is invalid, at ./src/rcl/publisher.c:423, at ./src/rcl_lifecycle.c:368
[waypoint_follower-6] [WARN] [1714872674.017305831] [rclcpp_lifecycle]: Shutdown error in destruction of LifecycleNode: final state(unconfigured)
[smoother_server-2] [INFO] [1714872674.019036856] [smoother_server]: Destroying
[smoother_server-2] [ERROR] [1714872674.019078348] [smoother_server]: Unable to start transition 5 from current state shuttingdown: Could not publish transition: publisher's context is invalid, at ./src/rcl/publisher.c:423, at ./src/rcl_lifecycle.c:368
[smoother_server-2] [WARN] [1714872674.019100717] [rclcpp_lifecycle]: Shutdown error in destruction of LifecycleNode: final state(unconfigured)
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1714872674.026250153] [planner_server]: Cleaning up plugin GridBased of type NavfnPlanner
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1714872674.026520816] [planner_server]: Destroying plugin GridBased of type NavfnPlanner
'discarding message because the queue is full'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872661.215012807] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872660.846 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872661.406279288] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872661.005 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872661.606534181] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872661.153 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872661.691020836] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872661.313 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872661.843230097] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872661.472 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872661.999587398] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872661.632 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872662.159502495] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872661.778 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872662.324098810] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872661.939 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872662.466329002] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872662.099 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872662.666582165] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872662.246 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872662.782662925] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872662.405 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872662.983212438] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872662.565 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872663.093834773] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872662.724 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872663.256889963] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872662.872 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872663.417987901] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872663.037 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872663.575852748] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872663.197 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1714872663.776313734] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1714872663.357 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache

from the pi :
[twist_mux-2] 
[twist_mux-2] >>> [rcutils|error_handling.c:108] rcutils_set_error_state()
[twist_mux-2] This error state is being overwritten:
[twist_mux-2] 
[twist_mux-2]   'Fast CDR exception deserializing message of type rmw_dds_common::msg::dds_::ParticipantEntitiesInfo_., at ./src/type_support_common.cpp:118'
[twist_mux-2] 
[twist_mux-2] with this new error message:
[twist_mux-2] 
[twist_mux-2]   ''Bad alloc' exception deserializing message of type rmw_dds_common::msg::dds_::ParticipantEntitiesInfo_., at ./src/type_support_common.cpp:123'
[twist_mux-2] 
[twist_mux-2] rcutils_reset_error() should be called after error handling to avoid this.
[twist_mux-2] <<<
[ros2_control_node-3] 
[ros2_control_node-3] >>> [rcutils|error_handling.c:108] rcutils_set_error_state()
[ros2_control_node-3] This error state is being overwritten:
[ros2_control_node-3] 
[ros2_control_node-3]   'Fast CDR exception deserializing message of type rmw_dds_common::msg::dds_::ParticipantEntitiesInfo_., at ./src/type_support_common.cpp:118'
[ros2_control_node-3] 
[ros2_control_node-3] with this new error message:
[ros2_control_node-3] 
[ros2_control_node-3]   ''Bad alloc' exception deserializing message of type rmw_dds_common::msg::dds_::ParticipantEntitiesInfo_., at ./src/type_support_common.cpp:123'
[ros2_control_node-3] 
[ros2_control_node-3] rcutils_reset_error() should be called after error handling to avoid this.
[ros2_control_node-3] <<<

from the pi (lidar):
rent scan mode: Sensitivity, sample rate: 8 Khz, max_distance: 12.0 m, scan frequency:10.0 Hz, 
[rplidar_node-1] 
[rplidar_node-1] >>> [rcutils|error_handling.c:108] rcutils_set_error_state()
[rplidar_node-1] This error state is being overwritten:
[rplidar_node-1] 
[rplidar_node-1]   'Fast CDR exception deserializing message of type rmw_dds_common::msg::dds_::ParticipantEntitiesInfo_., at ./src/type_support_common.cpp:118'
[rplidar_node-1] 
[rplidar_node-1] with this new error message:
[rplidar_node-1] 
[rplidar_node-1]   ''Bad alloc' exception deserializing message of type rmw_dds_common::msg::dds_::ParticipantEntitiesInfo_., at ./src/type_support_common.cpp:123'
[rplidar_node-1] 
[rplidar_node-1] rcutils_reset_error() should be called after error handling to avoid this.
[rplidar_node-1] <<<

I am not an expert, and I hope I can understand your instructions. I am running ROS Iron on my laptop and ROS Humble on my Pi.
